# Converting time to mm:dd:yyyy format

Tags: c#, datetime

I've time in milliseconds (I hope, still understanding datetime in C#) and want to convert it to mm:dd:yyyy format.

```
new DateTime(long.Parse("508289126400004")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Getting wrong answer:
Correct - 5/17/2014
I got - 08/12/0002
```

Any idea?

Quick link to try - http://ideone.com/VvixiE

Comment: what's that number? time in millisecond starting from which date? is a date or a datet/time?

Comment: Why do you expect `5/17/2014`, how have you converted it to that number?

Comment: I'd expect an input more like 635358816000000000 than 508289126400004 for that expected output...

Comment: I see - does it mean there should be some starting reference point (date) from which this number could match to the expected output?

Comment: of course. it could be from the days of Archimedes or Birth of Christ or your birthday.. whatever

Comment: Btw. `DateTime.MinValue.AddMilliseconds(508289126400004L)` throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. -- So it's hard to imagine this to be a "useful" amount of milliseconds.

Comment: Where are you getting that number from?  What sort of system is producing it?  It's clearly well out of range for a unixtime or similar.

Comment: @Corak Yes, because `DateTime(Int64)` constructor takes `Ticks` as a parameter but `AddMilliseconds(double)` takes milliseconds (which is 10.000 ticks every one of them). That's why it throws this exception.

Comment: Another btw.: 508289126400004 milliseconds are more than 16100 years...

Comment: @SonerGönül - Yes, and OP says "I've time in milliseconds".

Comment: @Corak Yeah, it throws the exception with milliseconds part as well. Maybe even OP have no idea why this number _should_ generate this `5/17/2014` date either.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your result is correct.

Because you are calling [`DateTime (Int64)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) which is

> Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to a specified
>   number of **ticks**.

And these ticks are;

> A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   that have elapsed **since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the
>   Gregorian calendar.**

It is *really* hard to understand why this long number should generate `5/17/2014` date. If you wanna have specific explanation about why this number generate this DateTime, please consider to add to your question.

By the way, you said `mm` in your title but formatted with `MM` in your question. Be aware, `mm` is for minutes and `MM` is for months. Custom date and time specifiers are case sensitive.

Also you are using [`/` date separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) without any culture in your `ToString` method. This separator has a special meaning as: *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That means, if your `CurrentCulture`'s [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is different than `/` character, the string representation will not include this `/` character anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your ticks.

```
long beginTicks = new DateTime(404,9, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;

DateTime dt = new DateTime(beginTicks + long.Parse("508289126400004") * 1000, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Where are these `404`, `9`, `2` and `* 1000` numbers coming from?